# MySQL Stored Procedure to loop through 2 tables, select values, and store in 3rd

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables `users`, `memos`, and `memos_read`.

`users`:

```
+---+----------+
|ID | NAME     |
+---+----------+
| 1 | Mike     |
| 4 | Susan    |
| 5 | Peter    |
| 6 | Mary     |
+---+----------+
```

`memos`:

```
+---+----------+
|ID | CONTENT  |
+---+----------+
| 15| Hello    |
| 16| World    |
| 17| Foo      |
| 23| Bar      |
+---+----------+
```

I want to create a stored procedure with a nested loop to create a "read map" for memos that have been read, creating something like:

`memos_read`:

```
+---------+----------+
| MEMO_ID | USER_ID  |
+---------+----------+
|    15   |    1     |
|    15   |    4     |
|    15   |    5     |
|    15   |    6     |
|    16   |    1     |
|    16   |    4     |
|    16   |    5     |
|    16   |    6     |
|    17   |    1     |
|    17   |    4     |
|    17   |    5     |
|    17   |    6     |
|    23   |    1     |
|    23   |    4     |
|    23   |    5     |
|    23   |    6     |
+---------+----------+
```

Is this possible? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: That's just a cross join no sp required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53441836/2469308) should work for you; however if you are not interested in creating a new table, and rather use the "read map" dynamically inside a query; you can utilize a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).

General query structure would be something as follows:

```
SELECT
  read_map.MEMO_ID,
  read_map.USER_ID,
  ...
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    m.ID AS MEMO_ID, 
    u.ID AS USER_ID
  FROM users AS u 
  CROSS JOIN memos AS m 
) AS read_map 

...  -- here you can join with other tables as required
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) syntax to create the `memos_read` table:

```
CREATE TABLE memos_read AS
SELECT m.ID AS MEMO_ID, u.ID AS USER_ID
FROM memos m 
CROSS JOIN users u
```

Output is as you requested. [Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6036c9aca265ba1b778c91ad34e412da)